# Cosmos DB call never returns with async call

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a method in a WebApi that calls Cosmos via the SQL API that returns process configuration files but will never return. The task hangs and never finishes. I can see the task in the Threads window in Debug. Other calls to the same database container run just fine. After several calls, I have to restart IIS to clear the Tasks. No exceptions are thrown. I've run it with and without try catches. The same method copied into another console app project works properly. Are there any known issues of cosmos timing out with too large a result? This should only return 2 items. The behavior is the same with a live Cosmos DB and the Cosmos Emulator running locally.

I'm using the latest Cosmos package.

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
```

Constructor

```
client = new CosmosClient(url, primaryKey, new CosmosClientOptions()
{
    RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20),
    ApplicationRegion = "West US 2",
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
    GatewayModeMaxConnectionLimit = 1000,
    MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 1000,
});

database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
container = configDatabase.GetContainer("Configs");
```

This method never returns from the await items.ReadNextAsync()

```
public async Task<Dictionary<int, string>> GetConfigurationList()
{
   var values = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.ConfigId, c.ConfigDescription FROM c where c.DataSourceType='CSV'");

   var items = container.GetItemQueryIterator<(int ConfigId, string ConfigDescription )>(query);

   while (items.HasMoreResults)
   {
       FeedResponse<(int ConfigId, string ConfigDescription )> configs = await items.ReadNextAsync();

       foreach (var item in configs)
       {
            values.Add(item.ConfigId, item.ConfigDescription);
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

This method works fine every time

```
public async Task<LetterConfiguration> GetConfiguration(int id)
{
  var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c where c.ConfigId= @id").WithParameter("@id",id);

  var configItems = container.GetItemQueryIterator<ConfigFile>(query);

  while (configItems.HasMoreResults)
  {
     FeedResponse<ConfigFile> configs = await configItems.ReadNextAsync();
     if(configs.Count == 1)
     {
        return configs.FirstOrDefault();
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you use typed object i.e. `ConfigFile` instead of `Tuple` in method `GetConfigurationList`. Also few other queries - What is the application you are developing? Is anywhere in the chain, does your code break async/await pattern? A suggestion to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for async call.

Comment: Using the typed object does the same thing. I tried to Tuple to see if it was a data volume issue. The async/await is used all the way from the controller to the repository this is in. The application is for generating form letter. The ConfigFiles define how to populate the data on different forms. I tried the ConfigureAwait(false) and it still doesn't return.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint at the end (last line) of the Web API method, does it get hit? If it is, you might be missing some `await` somewhere and losing the async context

Comment: The breakpoint never gets hit and the request from the caller (swagger UI, postman) never complete.

Comment: @kekindt - When you run this query directly in Comos DB Query blade (in Azure Portal) then does the query yield any result?

Comment: Have you tried with a smaller query? Maybe that query is returning a lot of results, and taking longer than the expected. Web requests often have a timeout after which they stop the request. Instead of iterating on all the pages, try stopping/breaking after the first one or reducing the query results and see if that is the case. When creating Web APIs, it is often the case that you would send back the Continuation Token and work paging the results if the # of results is too big.

Comment: There are only two items in the container for testing right now. It runs fine from Data Explorer on the Portal and it runs from the console app properly. Just not from the web api project.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up being a missing await in the controller calling the repository method. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of recommendations:

1. Did you check if there is any exception when calling ReadNextAsync? Use Try...Catch
2. Use typed Object for GetItemQueryIterator and FeedResponse

**Update**: Try this out for querying selective fields -

```
            var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.ConfigId, c.ConfigDescription FROM c where c.DataSourceType='CSV'");

            var items = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(query);


            while (items.HasMoreResults)
            {
                using (ResponseMessage response = await items.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(response.Content))
                    using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(sReader))
                    {
                        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                        dynamic values = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonReader).Documents;
                        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {values[0].ConfigId}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: 1. No exception gets thrown when using a try catch. 2. Using the typed object does the same thing. I tried to Tuple to see if it was a data volume issue.

Comment: Is letterContainers object getting set properly?

Comment: Yes it is. I renamed some variables after a review and hadn't compiled it again yet. I've fixed it in the example. Sorry.

Comment: Did you try a simple query (just in case to rule out any foul play here) - "SELECT * FROM c" ?
Sorry cannot think of any obvious reason. It certainly looks good and there is no perf concern with Cosmos DB.