# Why does accessing a container in cosmos immediately exit with no exception?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I started with a bog standard cosmos query example in C#.

When the code hits this line, it exits with no further information:

```
var currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
```

To verify something was working, I created this snippet:

```
this.cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUri, PrimaryKey);
this.container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

// This code worked and I verified results in data explorer
var deltest = this.cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, "deleteme");
deltest.DeleteContainerAsync().Wait();  

// this exits immediately, no exception
var a = await this.container.ReadContainerAsync();
```

The ReadContainerAsync left an important clue I did not see in the query code:

```
DocDBTrace Information: 0 : Azure Environment metadata information not available. A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80)
```

I have looked through the container setup, and I don't see anything.  Is there an option I need to enable to allow the container to be queryable?

**EDIT 1**

After playing with this for a bit.  I am encountering behavior I would not normally expect to see.  A bit of boring background:

- I am doing TDD with a unit test project for a .NET 6 library
- I am testing a class implementing an interface that hides the DB from the caller
- Class has a constructor and a single async method

This **TEST** code in the constructor works:

```
var deltest = this.cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, "deletetesttwo");
deltest.DeleteContainerAsync().Wait();
```

This **TEST** code in the async method exits the unit test project debug mode instantly:

```
var deltest = this.cosmosClient.GetContainer(databaseId, "deletetesttwo");
await deltest.DeleteContainerAsync();
```

I am recreating containers using data explorer between invocations.

Comment: What is the containerId of the container you are getting in `GetContainer()`? And why are you using .Wait()? That is highly unadvisable.

Comment: The .wait() is not a permanent fixture.  This is just code to get off the ground.  The containerId I am using is the string I see in data explorer.  Which happens to be "zipinfo" in this case.

Comment: What's the context? Is this running in an `async void` method?

Comment: The async method returns Task<T> where T is some private class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FACEPALM**

After looking at this: [Cosmos DB call never returns with async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612908/cosmos-db-call-never-returns-with-async-call?rq=1)

**Remember kids**: A unit test project example test method isn't async when you first create the class.

Changing the test method to async and adding await fixed the issue.